# Timer and TimerTask period is wrong

Tags: java, android, timer, timertask

I'm trying to capture raw video-data from Android Camera.
I'm using Timer+TimerTask pattern.

```
long lastT = System.currentTimeMillis();
long curT = System.currentTimeMillis();
    timertask = new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {


                    curT = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    Log.d(TAG_VIDEO,">>\t" + (curT - lastT) + "\t::\t");// + data.length);
                    lastT = curT;
}
};
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timertask, 0L, 1000L/15L);
```

But LogCat says inner tread launches every 3-170 ms. Omg why? How to fix it?
The other methods (Handler, Thread) give the same result.
The log:

```
11-05 17:54:27.550:  >> 67  ::  
11-05 17:54:27.620:  >> 65  ::  
11-05 17:54:27.685:  >> 66  ::  
11-05 17:54:27.750:  >> 66  ::  
11-05 17:54:27.815:  >> 66  ::  
11-05 17:54:27.880:  >> 67  ::  
11-05 17:54:27.945:  >> 65  ::  
11-05 17:54:28.015:  >> 66  ::  
11-05 17:54:28.080:  >> 66  ::  
11-05 17:54:28.145:  >> 66  ::  
11-05 17:54:28.250:  >> 66  ::  
11-05 17:54:28.280:  >> 68  ::  
11-05 17:54:28.450:  >> 168 ::  
11-05 17:54:28.450:  >> 3   ::  
11-05 17:54:28.475:  >> 25  ::  
11-05 17:54:28.550:  >> 77  ::  
11-05 17:54:28.650:  >> 95  ::  
11-05 17:54:28.675:  >> 26  ::  
11-05 17:54:28.740:  >> 66  ::  
11-05 17:54:28.805:  >> 66  ::  
11-05 17:54:28.930:  >> 76  ::  
11-05 17:54:28.940:  >> 57  ::  
11-05 17:54:29.125:  >> 95  ::  
11-05 17:54:29.130:  >> 95  ::  
11-05 17:54:29.160:  >> 30  ::  
11-05 17:54:29.280:  >> 69  ::  
11-05 17:54:29.280:  >> 51  ::  
11-05 17:54:29.380:  >> 103 ::  
11-05 17:54:29.470:  >> 48  ::  
11-05 17:54:29.470:  >> 41  ::  
11-05 17:54:29.575:  >> 105 ::  
11-05 17:54:29.670:  >> 44  ::  
11-05 17:54:29.670:  >> 50  ::  
11-05 17:54:29.765:  >> 91  ::  
11-05 17:54:29.855:  >> 49  ::  
11-05 17:54:29.865:  >> 54  ::  
11-05 17:54:29.950:  >> 87  ::  
11-05 17:54:30.005:  >> 52  ::  
11-05 17:54:30.085:  >> 79  ::  
11-05 17:54:30.130:  >> 46  ::  
11-05 17:54:30.280:  >> 153 ::  
11-05 17:54:30.280:  >> 2   ::  
11-05 17:54:30.435:  >> 66  ::  
11-05 17:54:30.525:  >> 88  ::  
11-05 17:54:30.525:  >> 89  ::  
11-05 17:54:30.525:  >> 0   ::  
11-05 17:54:30.600:  >> 63  ::  
11-05 17:54:30.730:  >> 79  ::  
11-05 17:54:30.730:  >> 63  ::  
11-05 17:54:30.835:  >> 56  ::  
11-05 17:54:30.940:  >> 106 ::  
11-05 17:54:30.940:  >> 48  ::  
11-05 17:54:31.055:  >> 67  ::  
11-05 17:54:31.055:  >> 47  ::  
11-05 17:54:31.210:  >> 148 ::  
11-05 17:54:31.210:  >> 6   ::  
11-05 17:54:31.335:  >> 65  ::  
11-05 17:54:31.335:  >> 62  ::  
11-05 17:54:31.450:  >> 61  ::  
11-05 17:54:31.450:  >> 55  ::  
11-05 17:54:31.535:  >> 84  ::  
11-05 17:54:31.605:  >> 70  ::  
11-05 17:54:31.675:  >> 69  ::  
11-05 17:54:31.755:  >> 35  ::  
11-05 17:54:31.855:  >> 99  ::  
11-05 17:54:31.860:  >> 49  ::  
11-05 17:54:31.950:  >> 94  ::  
11-05 17:54:32.045:  >> 54  ::  
11-05 17:54:32.045:  >> 41  ::  
11-05 17:54:32.200:  >> 102 ::  
11-05 17:54:32.200:  >> 50  ::  
11-05 17:54:32.335:  >> 66  ::  
11-05 17:54:32.335:  >> 69  ::  
11-05 17:54:32.440:  >> 52  ::  
11-05 17:54:32.440:  >> 55  ::  
11-05 17:54:32.550:  >> 106 ::  
11-05 17:54:32.640:  >> 53  ::  
11-05 17:54:32.645:  >> 42  ::  
11-05 17:54:32.760:  >> 64  ::  
11-05 17:54:32.765:  >> 61  ::  
11-05 17:54:32.865:  >> 91  ::  
11-05 17:54:32.980:  >> 58  ::  
11-05 17:54:32.980:  >> 66  ::  
11-05 17:54:33.100:  >> 60  ::  
11-05 17:54:33.100:  >> 59  ::  
11-05 17:54:33.235:  >> 127 ::  
11-05 17:54:33.235:  >> 6   ::  
11-05 17:54:33.340:  >> 106 ::  
11-05 17:54:33.430:  >> 52  ::  
11-05 17:54:33.440:  >> 40  ::  
11-05 17:54:33.535:  >> 103 ::  
11-05 17:54:33.650:  >> 48  ::  
11-05 17:54:33.650:  >> 68  ::  
11-05 17:54:33.760:  >> 52  ::  
11-05 17:54:33.760:  >> 59  ::  
11-05 17:54:33.860:  >> 91  ::  
11-05 17:54:34.065:  >> 42  ::  
11-05 17:54:34.100:  >> 172 ::  
11-05 17:54:34.100:  >> 36  ::  
11-05 17:54:34.105:  >> 2   ::  
11-05 17:54:34.220:  >> 76  ::  
11-05 17:54:34.230:  >> 40  ::  
11-05 17:54:34.370:  >> 112 ::  
11-05 17:54:34.370:  >> 38  ::  
11-05 17:54:34.505:  >> 84  ::  
11-05 17:54:34.505:  >> 52  ::  
11-05 17:54:34.590:  >> 41  ::  
11-05 17:54:34.670:  >> 82  ::  
11-05 17:54:34.750:  >> 80  ::  
11-05 17:54:34.750:  >> 42  ::  
11-05 17:54:34.830:  >> 77  ::  
11-05 17:54:34.905:  >> 74  ::  
11-05 17:54:35.005:  >> 41  ::  
11-05 17:54:35.010:  >> 67  ::  
11-05 17:54:35.105:  >> 92  ::  
11-05 17:54:35.235:  >> 61  ::  
11-05 17:54:35.235:  >> 74  ::  
11-05 17:54:35.370:  >> 68  ::  
11-05 17:54:35.370:  >> 66  ::  
11-05 17:54:35.475:  >> 53  ::  
11-05 17:54:35.475:  >> 50  ::  
11-05 17:54:35.580:  >> 106 ::  
11-05 17:54:35.670:  >> 50  ::  
11-05 17:54:35.675:  >> 43  ::  
11-05 17:54:35.735:  >> 62  ::  
11-05 17:54:35.800:  >> 67  ::  
11-05 17:54:35.865:  >> 65  ::  
11-05 17:54:35.935:  >> 66  ::  
11-05 17:54:36.000:  >> 66  ::  
11-05 17:54:36.065:  >> 66  ::  
11-05 17:54:36.130:  >> 67  ::  
11-05 17:54:36.195:  >> 65  ::  
11-05 17:54:36.265:  >> 66  ::  
11-05 17:54:36.415:  >> 105 ::  
11-05 17:54:36.415:  >> 46  ::  
11-05 17:54:36.460:  >> 47  ::  
11-05 17:54:36.525:  >> 66  ::  
11-05 17:54:36.595:  >> 66  ::  
11-05 17:54:36.660:  >> 68  ::  
11-05 17:54:36.725:  >> 64  ::  
11-05 17:54:36.790:  >> 66  ::  
11-05 17:54:36.860:  >> 67  ::  
11-05 17:54:36.925:  >> 66  ::  
11-05 17:54:37.130:  >> 202 ::  
11-05 17:54:37.135:  >> 3   ::  
11-05 17:54:37.140:  >> 8   ::  
11-05 17:54:37.200:  >> 57  ::  
11-05 17:54:37.255:  >> 59  ::  
11-05 17:54:37.320:  >> 67  ::  
11-05 17:54:37.385:  >> 66  ::  
11-05 17:54:37.465:  >> 77  ::  
11-05 17:54:37.850:  >> 140 ::  
11-05 17:54:37.855:  >> 250 ::  
11-05 17:54:37.855:  >> 2   ::  
11-05 17:54:37.855:  >> 1   ::  
11-05 17:54:37.855:  >> 1   ::  
11-05 17:54:37.860:  >> 0   ::  
11-05 17:54:37.915:  >> 58  ::  
11-05 17:54:37.985:  >> 68  ::  
11-05 17:54:38.165:  >> 93  ::  
11-05 17:54:38.165:  >> 90  ::  
11-05 17:54:38.180:  >> 13  ::  
11-05 17:54:38.600:  >> 82  ::  
11-05 17:54:38.610:  >> 337 ::  
11-05 17:54:38.610:  >> 10  ::  
11-05 17:54:38.610:  >> 2   ::  
11-05 17:54:38.610:  >> 1   ::  
11-05 17:54:38.610:  >> 0   ::  
11-05 17:54:38.650:  >> 37  ::  
11-05 17:54:38.850:  >> 131 ::  
11-05 17:54:39.130:  >> 137 ::  
11-05 17:54:39.130:  >> 212 ::  
11-05 17:54:39.130:  >> 0   ::  
11-05 17:54:39.130:  >> 0   ::  
11-05 17:54:39.130:  >> 0   ::  
11-05 17:54:39.130:  >> 0   ::  
11-05 17:54:39.265:  >> 69  ::  
11-05 17:54:39.270:  >> 70  ::  
11-05 17:54:39.420:  >> 62  ::  
11-05 17:54:39.420:  >> 90  ::  
11-05 17:54:39.640:  >> 63  ::  
11-05 17:54:39.640:  >> 157 ::  
11-05 17:54:39.640:  >> 1   ::  
11-05 17:54:39.640:  >> 1   ::  
11-05 17:54:39.745:  >> 55  ::  
11-05 17:54:39.765:  >> 67  ::  
11-05 17:54:39.895:  >> 133 ::  
11-05 17:54:39.895:  >> 1   ::  
11-05 17:54:40.035:  >> 63  ::  
11-05 17:54:40.035:  >> 73  ::  
11-05 17:54:40.200:  >> 72  ::  
11-05 17:54:40.205:  >> 99  ::  
11-05 17:54:40.405:  >> 63  ::  
11-05 17:54:40.405:  >> 136 ::  
11-05 17:54:40.405:  >> 0   ::  
11-05 17:54:40.425:  >> 20  ::  
11-05 17:54:40.575:  >> 68  ::  
11-05 17:54:40.575:  >> 82  ::  
11-05 17:54:40.840:  >> 90  ::  
11-05 17:54:40.900:  >> 233 ::  
11-05 17:54:40.900:  >> 3   ::  
11-05 17:54:40.910:  >> 9   ::  
11-05 17:54:40.910:  >> 3   ::  
11-05 17:54:41.010:  >> 47  ::  
11-05 17:54:41.015:  >> 57  ::  
11-05 17:54:41.110:  >> 95  ::  
11-05 17:54:41.265:  >> 58  ::  
11-05 17:54:41.270:  >> 100 ::  
11-05 17:54:41.425:  >> 73  ::  
11-05 17:54:41.425:  >> 82  ::  
11-05 17:54:41.425:  >> 0   ::  
11-05 17:54:41.510:  >> 86  ::  
11-05 17:54:41.595:  >> 46  ::  
11-05 17:54:41.700:  >> 76  ::  
11-05 17:54:41.700:  >> 68  ::  
11-05 17:54:41.815:  >> 61  ::  
11-05 17:54:41.815:  >> 56  ::  
11-05 17:54:42.010:  >> 75  ::  
11-05 17:54:42.080:  >> 119 ::  
11-05 17:54:42.080:  >> 71  ::  
11-05 17:54:42.080:  >> 1   ::  
11-05 17:54:42.340:  >> 137 ::  
11-05 17:54:42.340:  >> 121 ::  
11-05 17:54:42.340:  >> 0   ::  
11-05 17:54:42.340:  >> 0   ::  
11-05 17:54:42.485:  >> 79  ::  
11-05 17:54:42.485:  >> 64  ::  
11-05 17:54:42.535:  >> 53  ::  
11-05 17:54:42.645:  >> 106 ::  
11-05 17:54:42.850:  >> 56  ::  
11-05 17:54:42.850:  >> 151 ::  
11-05 17:54:42.850:  >> 1   ::  
11-05 17:54:42.895:  >> 41  ::  
11-05 17:54:43.030:  >> 74  ::  
11-05 17:54:43.035:  >> 68  ::  
11-05 17:54:43.200:  >> 62  ::  
11-05 17:54:43.200:  >> 104 ::  
11-05 17:54:43.200:  >> 0   ::  
11-05 17:54:43.365:  >> 70  ::  
11-05 17:54:43.365:  >> 95  ::  
11-05 17:54:43.495:  >> 70  ::  
11-05 17:54:43.495:  >> 60  ::  
11-05 17:54:43.695:  >> 101 ::  
11-05 17:54:43.695:  >> 98  ::  
11-05 17:54:43.695:  >> 0   ::  
11-05 17:54:43.790:  >> 46  ::  
11-05 17:54:43.790:  >> 53  ::  
11-05 17:54:43.900:  >> 101 ::  
11-05 17:54:44.000:  >> 48  ::  
11-05 17:54:44.000:  >> 58  ::  
11-05 17:54:44.155:  >> 70  ::  
11-05 17:54:44.155:  >> 88  ::  
11-05 17:54:44.380:  >> 98  ::  
11-05 17:54:44.385:  >> 126 ::  
11-05 17:54:44.385:  >> 2   ::  
11-05 17:54:44.385:  >> 3   ::  
11-05 17:54:44.535:  >> 149 ::  
11-05 17:54:44.535:  >> 0   ::  
11-05 17:54:44.945:  >> 91  ::  
11-05 17:54:44.945:  >> 316 ::  
11-05 17:54:44.945:  >> 1   ::  
11-05 17:54:44.945:  >> 0   ::  
11-05 17:54:44.945:  >> 0   ::  
11-05 17:54:44.945:  >> 0   ::  
11-05 17:54:44.995:  >> 48  ::  
11-05 17:54:45.115:  >> 70  ::  
11-05 17:54:45.115:  >> 53  ::  
11-05 17:54:45.260:  >> 65  ::  
11-05 17:54:45.260:  >> 82  ::  
11-05 17:54:45.365:  >> 64  ::  
11-05 17:54:45.370:  >> 46  ::  
11-05 17:54:45.475:  >> 101 ::  
11-05 17:54:45.590:  >> 58  ::  
11-05 17:54:45.590:  >> 58  ::  
11-05 17:54:45.700:  >> 57  ::  
11-05 17:54:45.700:  >> 56  ::  
11-05 17:54:45.825:  >> 121 ::  
11-05 17:54:45.915:  >> 47  ::  
11-05 17:54:45.915:  >> 44  ::  
11-05 17:54:46.015:  >> 99  ::  
11-05 17:54:46.130:  >> 61  ::  
11-05 17:54:46.130:  >> 58  ::  
11-05 17:54:46.265:  >> 134 ::  
11-05 17:54:46.270:  >> 3   ::  
11-05 17:54:46.500:  >> 71  ::  
11-05 17:54:46.500:  >> 160 ::  
11-05 17:54:46.500:  >> 0   ::  
11-05 17:54:46.500:  >> 0   ::  
11-05 17:54:46.560:  >> 60  ::  
11-05 17:54:46.645:  >> 85  ::  
11-05 17:54:46.765:  >> 52  ::  
11-05 17:54:46.765:  >> 68  ::  
11-05 17:54:46.855:  >> 90  ::  
11-05 17:54:46.940:  >> 44  ::  
11-05 17:54:47.025:  >> 78  ::  
11-05 17:54:47.025:  >> 51  ::  
11-05 17:54:47.125:  >> 97  ::  
11-05 17:54:47.240:  >> 45  ::  
11-05 17:54:47.240:  >> 70  ::  
11-05 17:54:47.360:  >> 47  ::  
11-05 17:54:47.450:  >> 115 ::  
11-05 17:54:47.455:  >> 52  ::  
11-05 17:54:47.540:  >> 47  ::  
11-05 17:54:47.550:  >> 49  ::  
11-05 17:54:47.625:  >> 77  ::  
11-05 17:54:47.710:  >> 84  ::  
11-05 17:54:47.800:  >> 42  ::  
11-05 17:54:47.815:  >> 61  ::  
11-05 17:54:47.895:  >> 78  ::  
11-05 17:54:47.970:  >> 78  ::  
11-05 17:54:48.070:  >> 44  ::  
11-05 17:54:48.155:  >> 91  ::  
11-05 17:54:48.155:  >> 49  ::  
11-05 17:54:48.260:  >> 60  ::  
11-05 17:54:48.470:  >> 85  ::  
11-05 17:54:48.470:  >> 170 ::  
11-05 17:54:48.470:  >> 0   ::  
11-05 17:54:48.570:  >> 45  ::  
11-05 17:54:48.570:  >> 59  ::  
11-05 17:54:48.605:  >> 33  ::  
11-05 17:54:48.735:  >> 69  ::  
11-05 17:54:48.740:  >> 64  ::
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are trying to do a real time image processing with Java and android. Java Runtime has a garbage collection mechanism that halt your app threads while it collects the unreferenced objects in the memory. So the variation you see (jitter) is due to the Garbage Collection thread that is running.

Comment: The loop has this lag even when I am trying to use the code directly I wrote before. No other image-using methods.just simple timertask

Comment: So maybe try to change the priority of the timer. http://stackoverflow.com/q/18739748/588532